# defining lastchild of div inside ul tags

Tags: html, css

My structure looks like this:

```
<div style="">                                                                                       
<ul>      
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <div class="border">
     <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>

<ul>      
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <div class="border">
     <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to select div.border:last-child but when I write in my css file

```
//css-file//
.border:last-child: solid 1px black;
//or//
div .border:last-child: solid 1px black;
//or//
div ul .border:last-child: solid 1px black;
```

The problem is my pseudo class :last-child is being ignored, all divs with border class get styled, I want only the last child get borders.

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/H3uKp/

I'm using google chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup is incorrect, an `ul` element cannot contain any other child element except `li`, what you can do is like this

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

and than use

```
ul li:last-of-type {
   border: /* Whatever */ ;
}
```

And if you want to target div than use

```
ul li:last-of-type div {
   border: /* Whatever */ ;
}
```

Comment: So having this structure in general 

     <ul>
        <div class"#">
           <li>aaa</li>
        </div>
      </ul>


Wouldn't be valide in wc3?

Comment: @MartynasDargis Obviously you can have classes and ids :)

Comment: this is not what I wanted to hear :( but i'll have to make it work with different methods, I made your answer correct, as it answer that you can' have divs inside ul, only li elements

Answer (score 0):

Actually another way of doing this would be like so

```
<div style="">                                                                                       
<ul>      
  <h1>Some text</h1>
     <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
     <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then just add the styling

```
   li {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
    li:last-child {
        border: none;
    }
```

Tested this in jsFiddle and it works just fine.

Comment: of course but i dont want it like this, I will have many <li><li> elements in <ul></ul> tags and I do not want every li element to get styled separately, I want them to be in one big wrapper leaving out <h1></h1> tag out of this, but as I understood this can't be done with css/html, because the structure itself is not valid in wc3, correct?

Comment: @MartynasDargis The structure you presented earlier on wouldn't validate. However I am trying to understand exactly what you want to achieve?? Do you want to create a normal list and then just have the last <li> in the <ul> tags to be styled differently?? will this be for use in a menu or how are you planning on using it??